# Why is my sprite moving diagonally?

Tags: java, swing, animation, sprite, keylistener

I've watched this tutorial and followed what i'v learnt to have a rectangle that should move up,down,right n left upon pressing the arrow keys. However the only movement i am getting is diagonal movement that too by pressing left and right while up and down arrow keys arent doing any job apparently.

Can someone analyse my code and tell me why am i getting diagonal movement instead of left,right,up down movement? 
Thank you in anticipation.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class Paint extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int x=0, sx=0, y=0, sy=0;
    Timer t= new Timer(5,this);

    public Paint(){
        t.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            x=x+sx;
            y=y+sx;
            repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        int c= e.getKeyCode();

        if(c== KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            sx=-1;
            sy=0;
        }

        if(c== KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            sx=1;
            sy=0;
        }

        if(c== KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            sx=0;
            sy=-1;
        }

        if (c== KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            sx=0;
            sy=1;
        }
    }

        public static void main(String [] args){
            Paint p= new Paint();
            JFrame j= new JFrame();
            j.setTitle("Practice");
            j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            j.setSize(500,500);
            j.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            j.setVisible(true);
            j.add(p);

        }



    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    }
```

Comment: Voting to close this, since it turned out to be a typographical error. Glad we could help!

Answer (score 7):

See this piece of code:

```
            x=x+sx;
            y=y+sx; <--- should be sy
```